# Java matrix runtime error

Tags: java, matrix, spiral

**Exercise letter:**

Given a matrix of m x n elements (m rows, n columns), return all elements of the matrix in spiral order.

For example, Given the following matrix:

```
[
     [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     [ 4, 5, 6 ],
     [ 7, 8, 9 ]
    ]
    You should return [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5].
```

**Given code:**

```
public class Solution {
  public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
  }
}
```

**My code:**

```
public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
        if(matrix == null || (matrix.length == 0))
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int arriba = 0;
        int derecha = matrix[0].length - 1;
        int abajo = matrix.length - 1;
        int izquierda = 0;
        List<Integer> retorno = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i = izquierda; i <= derecha; i++)
                retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i]);
            arriba++;
            for(int i = arriba; i <= abajo; i++)
                 retorno.add(matrix[i][derecha]);
            derecha--;
            for(int i = derecha; i >= izquierda; i--)
                retorno.add(matrix[abajo][i]);
            abajo--;
            for(int i = abajo; i >= arriba; i--)
                retorno.add(matrix[i][izquierda]);
            izquierda++;
            if(izquierda >= derecha)
                return retorno;
        }
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 13: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Last executed input:
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Any suggestions? I can't really tell what is wrong. Why is it out of bounds?
Exercise can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix/)

Comment: What is line 13? What happens when you use the debugger?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake not referring the lines.
Line 13:                 retorno.add(matrix[i][arriba]);. About the debugger, I can't run the program. It's a web based teaching method.

Comment: `retorno.add(matrix[i][arriba])` is not in your code sample.

Comment: @Gendarme what do you mean? It's right below the first for.

Comment: No. That is `retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i])`. I think we found your error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its                 retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i]);. That was not the error, I copy pasted wrong. I got the error with retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i]); in line 13

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with your input. Show is your main.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109488/discussion-between-giovanni-ghisellini-and-gendarme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your method with this matrix:

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},
                  {2,3,4},
                  {3,4,5}};
```

and I did not get any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Your code does not seem to throw any errors.

However, I noticed that the output is not as expected. The output it gave me was `12345432` (only 8 numbers), missing the number `3` in the middle of the matrix.

After having a thorough look at your code I realised that the error lies in `if(izquierda >= derecha)`. If you change this to `if(izquierda > derecha)` it will not miss the `3`. For the same reason you did this, you need to also check for `arriba > abajo`, otherwise your program does not work for any matrix that has more columns than rows.

**Edit:** You need these checks after every for-loop.

I suggest you move the `return retorno;` outside the while-loop, and insert `break` in the checks:

```
public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
    if(matrix == null || (matrix.length == 0))
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int arriba = 0;
    int derecha = matrix[0].length - 1;
    int abajo = matrix.length - 1;
    int izquierda = 0;
    List<Integer> retorno = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i = izquierda; i <= derecha; i++)
            retorno.add(matrix[arriba][i]);
        arriba++;
        if(arriba > abajo)
            break;

        for(int i = arriba; i <= abajo; i++)
             retorno.add(matrix[i][derecha]);
        derecha--;
        if(izquierda > derecha)
            break;

        for(int i = derecha; i >= izquierda; i--)
            retorno.add(matrix[abajo][i]);
        abajo--;
        if(arriba > abajo)
            break;

        for(int i = abajo; i >= arriba; i--)
            retorno.add(matrix[i][izquierda]);
        izquierda++;
        if(izquierda > derecha)
            break;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

**Explanation of your code (by request):** Imagine you have a matrix with four persons standing around it - each on one side. These four persons are called `arriba`, `derecha`, `abajo`, and `izquierda`:

```
           arriba
          1 2 3 4 5
izquierda 2 3 4 5 6 derecha
          3 4 5 6 7
            abajo
```

These four people can see the line of numbers right in front of them:

- `arriba` sees `1 2 3 4 5`.
- `derecha` sees `5 6 7`.
- `abajo` sees `3 4 5 6 7`.
- `izquierda` sees `1 2 3`.

Whenever all the numbers in front of any of these persons are added to the list `retorno`, they jump forward one step. For example after the first for-loop, it looks like this:

```
          1 2 3 4 5
           arriba
izquierda 2 3 4 5 6 derecha
          3 4 5 6 7
            abajo
```

After the whole first iteration of the while-loop, they stand like this:

```
1           2 3 4         5
           arriba
2 izquierda 3 4 5 derecha 6
            abajo
3           4 5 6         7
```

- `arriba` is moving downwards.
- `derecha` is moving to the left.
- `abajo` is moving upwards.
- `izquierda` is moving to the right.

As soon as *any* of these two persons pass each other, you know that there are no numbers in between them and you need to stop the loop *immediately*. This is why you need to check if two persons have passed each other *every time*  someone takes a step (after every for-loop).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but try it with this matrix. There is an error
Submission Result: Wrong Answer More Details 

Input:
[[7],[9],[6]]
Output:
[7,9,6,9]
Expected:
[7,9,6]

Comment: Nice, you got it. Can i get your email or something to contact you and you explain me what you did exactly?

Comment: I need 20  reputation to answer in the chat. It was unintentional. How can I get one more reputation point? I've got 19.

Comment: I can't answer in the discussion we started. Can you send me your email or whatsapp there? Or explain me what the break; does and what did you change?

Comment: `break` stops the while-loop. Which means that it jumps to the end of the while-loop and continues to read the code after the loop. In this case it is `return retorno;`. I am editing my answer to explain your code to you.

Comment: Thank you, i've got 21 rep points but i still cant answer you in the discussion. Weird.

Comment: @giovannighisellini I edited to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[][] DIRECTIONS = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

static boolean movable(int r, int c, int height, int width, boolean[][] visited) {
    if (r < 0 || r >= height || c < 0 || c >= width)
        return false;
    return !visited[r][c];
}

public List<Integer> spiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int height = matrix.length;
    if (height == 0) return result;
    int width = matrix[0].length;
    if (width == 0) return result;
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[height][width];
    int direction = 0;
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
        result.add(matrix[r][c]);
        visited[r][c] = true;
        int[] directions = DIRECTIONS[direction % DIRECTIONS.length];
        if (!movable(r + directions[0], c + directions[1], height, width, visited))
            directions = DIRECTIONS[++direction % DIRECTIONS.length];
        r += directions[0];
        c += directions[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This really works, but you did it by yourself? Or you go the idea from the internet? I cant upload something that was already post anywhere else. Thank you.

Comment: This code is not easy to understand. An explanation to complete the code dump would make this a much better answer.